# NestJS -- Accessing app context in controller

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I have this code in main.ts:

```
async function bootstrap() {
    const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
        logger: new LoggerService(
            process.env.SERVER_NAME || 'server',
            process.env.LOG_LEVEL || 'debug'
        ),
    })
...
```

LoggerService:

```
import { LoggerService as NestLoggerService } from '@nestjs/common'
import * as Bunyan from 'bunyan'

export class LoggerService implements NestLoggerService {
    private readonly _logger: Bunyan

    constructor(name: string, level: string) {
        this._logger = Bunyan.createLogger({
            name,
            level: level as Bunyan.LogLevelString,
        }).child({
            
            app_name: name,
        })
    }
...
```

In my controller, how can I access the logger which is instantiated in app bootstrap process?

Answer (score 1):

From the official NestJS [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/logger#dependency-injection):

> To enable dependency injection for your custom logger, create a class that implements LoggerService and register that class as a provider in some module.

Then you should register it as the app logger like this:

```
app.useLogger(app.get(MyLogger));
```

And then you will be able to inject `MyLogger` into your controller, or anywhere that you need it.